# How to include zero in a string?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

How to count including the zero like `substr`  in php. I'm doing like this query.

```
$datavariable = $query->result();

$caldata = array();
foreach ($datavariable as $row) {
    $caldata[substr($row->start_date, 8, 2)] = $row->class;
}
```

If the date is `2019-05-06` it didn't get the `01-09` only the `10-up` can you help me or is their a function like that? I just want to get the `days`

Comment: Do you want to get only day and month?

Comment: Please consider using a library like Carbon https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ And create the month with `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $row->start_date)` Then you can use methods like `$date->getDay()` or `$date->getMonth()` etc... without having to worry.

Comment: can you post several results and what`s the result you want ?

Comment: @DanishAli just the day sir...

Comment: @BRjava i just want to get the days sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `substr()` to get the day from the date. Use `date()` and `strtotime()` for this

```
$day = date('d', strtotime($row->start_date));
$caldata[$day] = $row->class;
```

Read more about [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)